# django/nginx - Using a context manager in wsgi.py

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-wsgi

**Situation:**

---

We have a *Django* application that has an ordinary `wsgi.py` module which creates an application *(`WSGIHandler`)* when run. The application is then served via *Nginx*.

**Problem:**

---

There should be some startup code that executes once when the `wsgi.py` executes. Specifically code that:

- Does some initialization of the interpreter process **before** django is initialized.
- Does some things **after** django is initialized *(`django.setup()` is called)*.

**Current solution:**

---

The way I implemented it by now is with a context manager *(see code below)*. It looks a bit awkward at first glance, but it performs as expected.

**Question:**

---

- When will *Nginx* start to serve requests to the `WSGIHandler` (pointed to by the module variable `application`)?
- Will it start serving request data to `application` before `__exit__()` has finished?
- My *(uneducated)* guess would be, that *Nginx* executes `wsgi.py` in script-style top-to-bottom once, and after that's done, accesses the module variable named `application`. Anybody knows better?
- How does this setup look to you? *Valid? Unorthodox, but technically valid? Problematic?*

---

---

**wsgi.cfg** *(pseudocode)*

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_test.settings")

from startup import StartupContext

with StartupContext():
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**startup.py**

```
class StartupContext():

    def __enter__(self):
        """Run before django.setup() is called."""
        setup_logging_for_python_process()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """Run after django.setup() is called."""
        call_command(["showmigrations", "--plan"])
```